# Recommended charger for iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, power, charger

I can see on the Apple store that the standard charger is a **12W** charger.

Since it "should" output **5V**, I can conclude it outputs **2.4A** (12W/5V=2.4A).

Considering the above hypothesis correct, could any charger having the same output be used for my iPhone 5?

Comment: This already has an answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244100/180636), which gives suggestions for iPhone cables to buy on Amazon.com/Apple.com.

Comment: Please use apple genuine chargers! I.E the one that came with the phone!
it outputs 5V/1A, 2.4A is to much for that single cell LION.

Comment: I doubt this 12W power adapter outputs 1A http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter , but rather 2.4A as explained in the question. All iPhone models are listed in the compatibility list though (along with all iPads). Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, theoretically that's correct and there are thousands of chargers out there that will work with Apple products.  However, Apple includes specific components in their chargers to ensure their charging and communication protocols are followed.  They also have a licensing program for 3rd-party companies to manufacture and sell Apple-certified products, [the MFI program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

If you are looking for charging devices not manufactured by Apple but still follow the Apple-certification process, make sure the products display the MFI certication logo (not the 'Compatible with iPhone' logo which actually means nothing).

Comment: Super interesting. Do you think the charging/communication protocols actually affect the quality of the charge? As in, would a non-MFI-certified have any negative effect on the Apple device (i.e. damage the battery)?

Comment: It could but it's impossible to say.  Because they're not following the proper Apple standards, they could say one thing but actually do another.  Personally, I don't use any charger or cable that isn't MFI certified.  It's not worth frying out my device.

Comment: Apple being so unclear about this, that's annoying. I guess you're right, it's probably not worth taking the risk. I'll get MFI certified chargers from now onwards.

Comment: I don't see it as Apple being unclear; they've always said not to use anything except their devices or MFI-certified.  They print the voltage, amps, etc. requirements on their site and also on the devices themselves.  I don't think it can get any clearer than that.